# GNU Parallel: Do not quote Perl replacement string values that contain spaces?

Tags: bash, perl, gnu-parallel

The script I am writing with `parallel` currently looks like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
seq ${2:-3} | parallel --tty -j0 sidplayfp -wch{}.wav '{=$_=join" ",map{"-u".$_}grep!/@{[seq()]}/,(1..total_jobs())=}' ${@:3} -q $1 '2>/dev/null'
```

For example, running `./sidrender.sh Stomp.sid` is expected to execute the following commands:

```sh
sidplayfp -wch1.wav -u2 -u3 -q Stomp.sid 2>/dev/null
sidplayfp -wch2.wav -u1 -u3 -q Stomp.sid 2>/dev/null
sidplayfp -wch3.wav -u1 -u2 -q Stomp.sid 2>/dev/null
```

However, this does not work properly, and when looking with `--dry-run`, it turns out that `parallel` is quoting together the `-u` flags (e.g. `sidplayfp -wch1.wav '-u2 -u3' -q Stomp.sid 2>/dev/null`) because they come from the same Perl expression.

Here's a minimal example of what is happening:

```sh
$ parallel --dry-run 'echo {= $_="foo bar" =}' ::: 1
echo 'foo bar'
```

If you were to replace `"foo bar"` with `"foo"`, the output would be `echo foo` without any quotes.

Because `sidplayfp` does not properly parse the arguments when they are quoted, I need a way to stop `parallel` from quoting the output, but I cannot find a way to do so in the man page.

Comment: Are you sure, you are seeing `echo 'foo bar'`? on `GNU parallel 20180622` I have I see `echo foo\ bar`

Comment: @Inian I'm using Arch Linux with `parallel 20190422`, `bash 5.0.7`, and `perl 5.30.0`, and I can verify this behavior on 2 different machines.

Comment: @Inian The quoting behaviour changed in 20180722.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `eval`:

```
seq ${2:-3} |
  parallel --tty -j0 eval sidplayfp -wch{}.wav '{=$_=join" ",map{"-u".$_}grep!/@{[seq()]}/,(1..total_jobs())=}' ${@:3} -q $1 '2>/dev/null'
```